# Nextcloud (docker) fails to connect to Mysql (docker) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]

Tags: mysql, docker, nextcloud

I have installed nextcloud with docker compose using the yaml file below

```
  GNU nano 4.8                                                                                docker-compose.yaml                                                                                          
version: "3"

services:
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextclouduser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html

volumes:
  nextcloud:
```

when is connect to it i fail to create an admin account with the error:
'Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution '

i have setup my database correctly (i think) when i sign in with nextclouduser i can see that the nextclouduser has access to nextcloud database

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| nextcloud          |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Where is the database configured?  It doesn't seem to be in the `docker-compose.yml` file you included.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same error while deploying docker nextcloud 23.0 by using an "older" version of mariadb :

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    # image: mariadb:latest
    image: mariadb:10.5.13
  ...  
  app:
    image: nextcloud:23.0.0-apache
  ...
```

If it could help...